# Excel vba module issue(?)

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I was trying to compute choleskyDecomposition in vba.

I made a module for testing and I made another module for final assignment.

here is my wondering point.
when I execute the testing module, I successfully computed Cholesky Decomposition matrix but when I execute the module which is for final assignment, I got error message that I made invalid procedures or argument.

I bloody can't figure it out why there is an issue in the assignment module even though I used exactly same code with testing module...

If you guys give me any input, I would be truly grateful for you guys' help...

Here is my comprehensive code...

```
Option Explicit
Function ComputingVolatility(s() As Double, n As Integer) As Double

    Dim R() As Double
    ReDim R(n)
    Dim Sum_R As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Avg_R As Double
    Dim Dev_R As Double
    Dim Stdev_R As Double
    
    'Computing Average of Return
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        R(i) = Log(s(i) / s(i + 1))
        Sum_R = Sum_R + R(i)
    Next
    Avg_R = Sum_R / n
    
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        Dev_R = Dev_R + (R(i) - Avg_R) ^ 2
    Next
    Stdev_R = Sqr(Dev_R / n)
    
    ComputingVolatility = Stdev_R * Sqr(n)
    
    
End Function
Function ComputingCorrelation(s1() As Double, s2() As Double, n As Integer) As Double
    
    Dim R1() As Double, R2() As Double
    ReDim R1(n)
    ReDim R2(n)
    Dim Sum_R1 As Double, Sum_R2 As Double
    Dim Avg_R1 As Double, Avg_R2 As Double
    Dim Cov As Double
    Dim Multiple As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        R1(i) = Log(s1(i) / s1(i + 1))
        Sum_R1 = Sum_R1 + R1(i)
        R2(i) = Log(s2(i) / s2(i + 1))
        Sum_R2 = Sum_R2 + R2(i)
    Next
    Avg_R1 = Sum_R1 / n
    Avg_R2 = Sum_R2 / n
    
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        Cov = Cov + (R1(i) - Avg_R1) * (R2(i) - Avg_R2)
    Next
        Cov = Cov / (n - 1)
        Multiple = ComputingVolatility(s1(), n) * ComputingVolatility(s2(), n) / n
    ComputingCorrelation = Cov / Multiple
    
End Function
Function CholeskyDecompositionF(mat() As Double, size As Long) As Double()
    Dim a() As Double, L() As Double, s As Double, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, sum As Double
    a = mat
    ReDim L(1 To size, 1 To size)
    
    For i = 1 To size
        For j = 1 To size
                If i = j Then
                    For k = 1 To j - 1
                        sum = sum + L(j, k) ^ 2
                    Next
                    L(j, j) = Sqr(a(j, j) - sum)
                    sum = 0
                ElseIf i > j Then
                    For k = 1 To j - 1
                        sum = sum + L(i, k) * L(j, k)
                    Next
                    L(i, j) = (a(i, j) - sum) / L(j, j)
                    sum = 0
                ElseIf i < j Then
                    L(i, j) = 0
                End If
            Next
    Next
    
    CholeskyDecompositionF = L
End Function
Sub Assignment()
    'For vol and corr
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim days As Integer
    'For Cholesky
    Dim mat() As Double
    ReDim mat(1 To 3, 1 To 3)
    Dim Chole() As Double
    ReDim Chole(1 To 3, 1 To 3)
    days = Cells(6, 1)
    'Bring data
    Dim IndexData As Worksheet
    Set IndexData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Adj Index")
    Dim KOSPI200() As Double
    ReDim KOSPI200(days)
    Dim SNP500() As Double
    ReDim SNP500(days)
    Dim STOXX50E() As Double
    ReDim STOXX50E(days)
    Dim NIKKEI225() As Double
    ReDim NIKKEI225(days)
    
    For i = 0 To days
        KOSPI200(i) = IndexData.Cells(i + 4, 2)
        SNP500(i) = IndexData.Cells(i + 4, 5)
        STOXX50E(i) = IndexData.Cells(i + 4, 8)
        NIKKEI225(i) = IndexData.Cells(i + 4, 11)
    Next

    'Releasing Vol
    Cells(8, 3) = ComputingVolatility(KOSPI200(), days)
    Cells(8, 4) = ComputingVolatility(SNP500(), days)
    Cells(8, 5) = ComputingVolatility(STOXX50E(), days)
    Cells(8, 6) = ComputingVolatility(NIKKEI225(), days)
    'Releasing Corr
    Cells(11, 3) = ComputingCorrelation(KOSPI200(), SNP500(), days)
    Cells(12, 3) = ComputingCorrelation(KOSPI200(), STOXX50E(), days)
    Cells(13, 3) = ComputingCorrelation(KOSPI200(), NIKKEI225(), days)
    Cells(11, 6) = ComputingCorrelation(SNP500(), STOXX50E(), days)
    Cells(12, 6) = ComputingCorrelation(SNP500(), NIKKEI225(), days)
    Cells(13, 6) = ComputingCorrelation(STOXX50E(), NIKKEI225(), days)
    
    'CholeskyDecomposition
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            mat(i, j) = Cells(i + 10, 3 * j)
        Next j
    Next i

    ' Apply Cholesky decomposition
    Chole = CholeskyDecompositionF(mat, 3)

    ' Output the result to the worksheet
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            Cells(i + 5, j + 10) = Chole(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Your code compiles OK, so we'd need to be able to run it to test.  For that we'd need to know what the input data looks like.

Comment: `execute the testing module` What's the testing module?

Comment: testing module was just for testing before I put the code to comprehensive module, which is "FinalAssignment".

I need to compute volatility, correlation and choleskydecomposition.
so, I made 3 of module and in each of module, I wrote function.
To sum up, In 1st module, there is function of computingVolatility, 2nd module for ComputingCorrelation, 3rd module for CholeskyDecomposition.
and in a 4th module, I put all of 3 module together so it would be finalAssignment model.

and when I run only 3rd module(Cholesky) there is no error msg at all but when I run 4th, I got error...

Comment: the data is like
KOSPI200 Index data, S&P500 Index data, STOXX50E, NIKKEI225 index data

Comment: In which line have you got an error and what is the error description? Show some sample data to test. Not everyone uses this index data on a daily basis.

Comment: Are you sure that the data is complete, that is, there are no errors, zeros, empty cells, etc.?

Comment: @MGonet hey just after I checked your comment, I checked the data I used.

Comment: in a testing code, I used another data and when I run the testing module with same data that I used when I run the FinalAssignment module, I got same error.
thanks for your advice! I am gonna check the data again.

and the line where I got error msg was
'''
L(j, j) = Sqr(a(j, j) - sum)
'''

Comment: and the data is like

11/27/00 326.71
11/28/00 326.9
12/3/00 331.58
12/3/00 332.02
12/5/00 333.04
12/9/00 338.75
12/6/00 338.82
11/30/00 340.67
11/30/00 344.98
12/2/00 341.19
12/1/00 335.99
12/1/00 335.54
12/2/00 337.58

Comment: The place of error suggests that probably you tried to calculate square root of a negative number. You should remember that Cholesky decomposition is not possible for all matrices, it requires a matrix to be positive-definite. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

Comment: Yes. It seems like... Thanks for your input! Have a good one!!!